# Switch case performance on large number of cases

Tags: c#, function

I am making a game in C# with multiple levels and i'm trying to make a `CreateLevel(int i)` function. Here is how it looks now:

```
void CreateLevel(int i)
{
    switch(i) {
    case 1: ...
    case 2: ...
    ...

    case 300: ...
    }
}
```

So this function is O(n) when it comes to `CreatingLevel(n);`, because it has to go through all n levels to find Level `n`. Is there a way to make this O(1) ? I am sure there has to be a better way than this, but i can't think of it.

**Edit:** Apparently `switch` method is actually **O(1)** according to the comments, it is not O(n). I will keep my post in its original format for the sake of the question.

Also, each level is a set of bricks with different colors in different positions which make images-looking shapes (like an umbrella or a tree), i code these information in a character array like so :

```
[ r, r, r, g, ' ', b, b] 
[ g, g, b, ' ', g, b, b] 
[ r, b, b, ' ', b, b, b]
```

Then i parse this array to create the game objects and finally fill the list with the current level's information to use it for the duration of the current level.

Comment: Is that a `switch` case statement?

Comment: If you use switch, it doesn't go through all the levels.. That's the point and the biggest difference compared to if-statements. However, it looks like a bad architectural design anyway...

Comment: That isn't O(n). It has constant values, it jumps to the matching statement. If none exist, it uses that `default` label using a jump table

Comment: @walther it is not O(n) ? i did not know that. if it is a bad architectural design as you say, how could it be improved ?

Comment: What varies between the different levels? This looks like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try spelling out what you *want to do*, not *how you want it done*

Comment: I believe Yuval already said that.. It's kinda hard to improve your code at the moment, because we don't know any details about your game. The topic is kinda broad and there are certainly many approaches on how to handle a situation like this => not really sure it fits SO 1-1 Q&A style.

Comment: @Shiro In C#, for  a `switch/case` statement with more than five values, the compiler generates a lookup table for the branches. Regarding design, what possible need could you have for 300 distinct logic cases in a single method invocation?

Comment: It's just `design` not `architectural design`

Comment: @MickyDuncan What does that sentence even mean?

Comment: @walther Im filling a List with the level details of the currect level i need to display to the screen. I'm using a `coded string` like "r r r g g r r r" and then i `parse` it to create the level.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sadly a proper explanation could not fit into 600 or so characters

Comment: @Shiro If you have performance in mind, i would encapsulate this piece of code inside a factory which would be in charge of generation these levels. Note that i'm not sure storing those level definitions inside a list is your best bet for performance.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The levels are obviously (?) not generated random, they are already made by hand, (representing picture-like shapes for example an umbrella)  and i am not storing the level definitions in a list, i am storing the `current level`'s game objects in the `current level list` which is being created by parsing the string that represents the level n, making the proper game objects and filling the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary<int, Action>`

```
var d = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
d.Add(1, () => Console.WriteLine("level 1"));
d.Add(2, () => Console.WriteLine("level 2"));
```

Then you can use it instead of a case statement

```
void CreateLevel(int i)
{
    d[i].Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Where's a benefit here? He's not asking to be able to add/remove cases, nor to be able to change the activity associated with a case. All this does is allow for run-time modifications that almost assuredly aren't desired.

Comment: I'd prefer this over a 300 case statement. If there was some redundancy in the cases, it might be able to be automated when adding levels.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - I disagree.  Verdolino's suggestion allows you to construct the set in what-ever means you wish, a setup that might be static or not; but when it comes to executing a step it is O(1).  I use it all the time in state machines

Comment: As i mentioned in the comments Im filling a List with the level details of the currect level i need to display to the screen. I'm using a coded string like "r r r g g r r r" and then i parse it to create the level, so every level is unique, if i  made a dictionary with 300 * k  strings would that not be terrible for the memory ? keep in mind this is a mobile game, i am just trying to increase performance, not make a framework or reusable code.

Comment: @shiro What framework are you using which allows you to develop mobile games in c#?